# TypeScript predefined method "onChange" is not a function Astro & React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm working with Astro and React and I'm having trouble passing a function in as a component.

```
<Tiptap client:only="react" id="content" description={''} onChange={(e) => {
    contentValue = e
    console.log(contentValue)
}}/>
```

Here is the implementation of Tiptap:

```
export default function Tiptap({description, onChange}: {description: string, onChange: (richText: string) => void}) {
    const editor = useEditor({
        extensions: [StarterKit.configure()],
        editorProps: {
            attributes: {
                class: 'rounded-md border min-h-[600px] border-input bg-back p-2'
            },
        },
        onUpdate({editor}){
            onChange(editor.getHTML())
        }
    })

    return (
        <div className='flex flex-col justify-stretch min-h-[600px]'>
            <Toolbar editor={editor} />
            <EditorContent editor={editor} />
        </div>
    )
}
```